# Quaternion euler angle going into negative for no reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I'm making a day-night cycle for my game. The way I do it, is that I have a **DateTime** to which I add seconds each second. I also have an integer **minutes** which is basically (DateTime.hours * 60 + DateTime.minutes).

I want to rotate the sun based on the **minutes** variable. The final equation is **Quaternion.Euler(minutes / 4, 0, 0)**.
All of that works until the **DateTime** reaches noon at this point, the sun starts glitching out going into negative then back to the right rotation until midnight.

At some point the inspector isn't showing the same values that a **Debug.Log** of the sun's rot shows.
[image]

Here's a video showing what happens. Sorry for the poor quality
https://youtu.be/_Gtb1h8feGs

I've seen somewhere that it might be due to the Gimbal lock. I'm not the best when it comes to quaternions so I might be talking nonsense. Anyways, here's my code

```cs
 public enum DayTime
{
    Morning,
    Noon,
    AfterNoon,
    Evening,
    Night
}

public class MoonTime : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DateTime date = new DateTime(2023, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    [HideInInspector]
    public float minutes = 0;
    public float dayLength = 4;

    public float smoothness = 4.5f;

    [HideInInspector]
    public DayTime dayTime;

    public delegate void TimeChange(DateTime date);
    public event TimeChange onTimeChange;

    public delegate void DayTimeChange(DayTime dayTime);
    public event DayTimeChange onDayTimeChange;


    public Material daySkyBox;
    public Material nightSkyBox;

    public Light Sun;
    public Light Moon;

    private void Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TimeClock());

        onTimeChange += (d) =>
        {
            var sunCurrentRot = Sun.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

            Debug.Log("What rot is should be " + Quaternion.Euler(minutes / 4, sunCurrentRot.y, sunCurrentRot.z).eulerAngles);
            Sun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(minutes / 4, sunCurrentRot.y, sunCurrentRot.z);
            Debug.Log("What is it " + Sun.transform.rotation.eulerAngles);

            //var moonCurrentRot = Moon.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

            //Moon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler((minutes * 0.25f) + 180, moonCurrentRot.y, moonCurrentRot.z);
        };
    }

    private void Update()
    {
    }

    public IEnumerator TimeClock()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1 / smoothness);

            float finalValue = 1440 / (dayLength * 60) / smoothness;

            date = date.AddSeconds(finalValue);

            minutes = (date.Hour * 60) + date.Minute;


            if (date.Hour >= 0 && date.Hour < 12)
            {
                if (dayTime != DayTime.Morning)
                {
                    dayTime = DayTime.Morning;
                    Debug.Log("Morning");
                    onDayTimeChange?.Invoke(DayTime.Morning);
                }
            }
            else if (date.Hour == 12)
            {
                if (dayTime != DayTime.Noon)
                {
                    dayTime = DayTime.Noon;
                    Debug.Log("Noon");
                    onDayTimeChange?.Invoke(DayTime.Noon);
                }
            }
            else if(date.Hour > 12 && date.Hour <= 15)
            {
                if (dayTime != DayTime.AfterNoon)
                {
                    dayTime = DayTime.AfterNoon;
                    Debug.Log("After Noon");
                    onDayTimeChange?.Invoke(DayTime.AfterNoon);
                }
            }
            else if (date.Hour > 15 && date.Hour <= 17)
            {
                if (dayTime != DayTime.Evening)
                {
                    dayTime = DayTime.Evening;
                    Debug.Log("Evening");
                    onDayTimeChange?.Invoke(DayTime.Evening);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (dayTime != DayTime.Night)
                {
                    dayTime = DayTime.Night;
                    Debug.Log("Night");
                    onDayTimeChange?.Invoke(DayTime.Night);
                }
            }

            onTimeChange?.Invoke(date);

            Debug.Log(date);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Note that 345.25deg rotation is the same as a -14.75deg rotation...

Comment: The only thing that looks like it'd be different here is that you're selectively calling a function you haven't shared with us - `onDayTimeChange`. What is this, and what happens when you pass it `DayTime.Night`? It's not in the snippet you've posted.

Comment: **onDayTimeChange** change is called in the **IEnumerator TimeClock(**) near the end of it

Comment: I can see that it's called. I can *not* see what it does.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that the sun starts acting weird at noon, and in your `TimeClock()` method the `if (date.Hour == 12)` block is the only one that doesn't have logic beyond `dayTime = [...]` and `Deblug.Log`?

Comment: @Chuck Whenever the state of the day changes (Morning, noon, evening, ...) I call it. I haven't used it in this snippet nor have I used it anywhere else.
In your previous comment you said **calling a function** but **onDayTimeChange** is an event

Comment: @Snapper "Whenever the state of the day changes (Morning, noon, evening, ...) I call it." that is not entirely correct; as I said, you do not call it within the `else if (date.Hour == 12)` block as you do with every other `DayTime` value.

Comment: I just now noticed that. Thanks for pointing that out. It's just an error on my side.
After correcting it, the sun seems so start glitching at 6 a.m now

Comment: @Snapper also note that in your checks you have `if (date.Hour >= 0 && date.Hour <= 12)` and then `else if (date.Hour == 12)`... but you're already checking `date.Hour <= 12`, so it won't ever reach `date.Hour == 12`, and you will never set `dayTime = DayTime.Noon`.

Comment: I must have coded this late at night. After fixing all of these, the sun is still glitching

Comment: `In your previous comment you said calling a function but onDayTimeChange is an event` -.- I'm trying to help you here, pal. Does it have any subscribers? Do those subscribers do anything?

Comment: I'm aware of that, sorry if it felt a bit harsh but that wasn't the intention at all. To answer your question, no, it does not have any subscribers. Just there for me to use in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only other fix I can think of is that sometimes Unity will alter the Quaternion-Euler conversion, such that two axes shift to keep another axis within some limits. I think these limits might be -90...90, but I'm not positive here.

I suspect the problem you're having is when you try to set the code by polling the current rotation and updating one angle. If unity has converted, for example, <91, 0, 0> to <1, 90, 90> or something similar, and you take that rotation and set the next x-angle to 92, then you wind up setting <92, 90, 90> instead of your intended <92, 0, 0>. These won't be the same as what you mean, and you'll wind up with Unity re-changing the coordinates to be within bounds again.

Two possible solutions here:

1. Apply incremental changes only, or
2. Cache the y/z rotations in Awake and use those.

I would strongly suggest option (2), because if you're only ever applying deltas then you'll find that floating-point limitations and other rounding errors will get you to the point that your sun is in the wrong position for the time of day.

Here's the suggested fix to your script:

```
private float sunY;
private float sunZ;
private void Awake()
{
    StartCoroutine(TimeClock());
    sunY = Sun.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
    sunZ = Sun.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
    onTimeChange += (d) =>
    {
        Debug.Log("What rot is should be " + Quaternion.Euler(minutes / 4, sunY, sunZ).eulerAngles);
        Sun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(minutes / 4, sunY, sunZ);
        Debug.Log("What is it " + Sun.transform.rotation.eulerAngles);

        //var moonCurrentRot = Moon.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

        //Moon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler((minutes * 0.25f) + 180, moonCurrentRot.y, moonCurrentRot.z);
    };
}
```

This should ensure your rotations stay the way you expect even if Unity's internal Quaternion-to-Euler conversion flips axes on you (because you're not starting from those values).